# How can I get rid of index error while printing nested list?

Tags: python, list, index-error

```
fruits = ["Strawberries", "Nectarines", "Apples", "Grapes", "Peaches", "Cherries", "Pears"]

vegetables = ["Spinach", "Kale", "Tomatoes", "Celery", "Potatoes"] 

dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]

print(dirty_dozen[-1][-3])
```

If the line of code above can be printed then why can't the one below can be printed?

```
print(dirty_dozen[-7])
```

Comment: format the code properly using triple backticks please ```

Comment: Because you are trying to access the 7th last element of a list that has only 2 elements (`fruits` and `vegetables`). You are probably looking for `print(dirty_dozen[-1][-7])`

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a nested List. The list `dirty_dozen` has a length of 2 so a index of -7 would be an index of -5 which is not possible.

The first example prints, because the first access is to the last element of the list, which is the vegetable list. The second access is the third last element of this list.

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of `dirty_dozen` with `print(len(dirty_dozen))` and you'll see that it has only 2 elements (the `fruits` and `vegetables` lists).

You can access the last element with `dirty_dozen[-1]` or the 2nd to last with `dirty_dozen[-2]`, but since there are only 2 sub-lists, accessing the -7th element is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

`dirty_dozen` has only two elements in it, since you initialized it as `dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]`. Accessing the "7th last element" will underflow the index, and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access `dirty_dozen[-7]`, then you might want to merge the lists into one list.

For example, either approach below should work:

```py
dirty_dozen = [*fruits, *vegetables]
# or: dirty_dozen = fruits + vegetables

print(dirty_dozen[-7])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits = ["Strawberries", "Nectarines", "Apples", "Grapes", "Peaches", "Cherries", "Pears"]
vegetables = ["Spinach", "Kale", "Tomatoes", "Celery", "Potatoes"]
 
dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]
 
print(dirty_dozen[1][1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).